# Nuget package not containing updated classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, package, nuget

I have a library that I pull into a number of projects.

Today I merged master into the branch of that library.

After the merge I created a new beta package to pull into my development branch project so that it would have everything from the main branch and all the changes used by the development branch.

When I pulled the new package into the project I have found that certain classes that were in the previous branched version are now missing.

Opening the PDP I can see that these classes are no longer included in the package and one class is missing a field that's clearly present in the library solution pushed to Nuget.

Class as it appears in the library project:

```
using Libraries.Models.Web.Interfaces;
using Libraries.Models.Web.Objects;
using Libraries.Models.Web.Page;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace Libraries.Models.Web.Subjects
{
    [PublicAPI]
    public class SubjectPage : WebPage, ISubjectPage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Video { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Decompiled class when pulled into API project:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Libraries.Models.Web.Subjects.SubjectPage
// Assembly: Libraries.Models.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: E2FEBB82-23D5-440C-989A-623618BBF3BA
// Assembly location: C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\libraries.models.web\1.0.22.1-beta05\lib\netstandard2.0\Libraries.Models.Web.dll

using Libraries.Models.Web.Interfaces;
using Libraries.Models.Web.Objects;
using Libraries.Models.Web.Page;

namespace Libraries.Models.Web.Subjects
{
  public class SubjectPage : WebPage, ISubjectPage
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Notice the "Video" field is missing from the decompiled file.

I haven't seen this behaviour before so why is it when I am packaging the library, it seems to be ignoring some of the classes and fields?

Comment: Assuming version was incremented in package before publishing to nuget library and it was also changed in the package.config file of consuming project, you might want to try clean project (delete `bin` and `obj` folders) and rebuild. If doesn't work, then clean close Visual Studio and then open and rebuild. Try building from Visual Studio Command Prompt using msbuild command

Comment: @IsmailS Thanks for the help. Yes version was incremated and consumed. I have tried deleting the bin and obj folders to no success. And as per your advice I've tried using the command line to build the project, sadly to no success there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question as I have found the reason for the issue.

Having used dotnet peek to investigate the Nuget package generated in my library solution I could see that all the missing items were present therefore this must be what is being uploaded to the Nuget server.

I then looked into where Nuget packages are stored under

```
C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\libraries.models.web
```

Where I noticed that the package version had a date of back in September.
I then remembered that there was a previously aborted development and the packages were removed from the Nuget server, but clearly not from the local user profile directory!

I wasn't aware that the packages were stored locally here, so the reason this failed for me was simple user error or knowledge gap.

Hopefully this question and answer can help someone else in future.